# Feed unquoted column name to R function [rpy2]

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I want to use `ICCest` (a function in R library `ICC`) in Python with the help of rpy2.

The usage of [ICCest](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ICC/versions/2.3.0/topics/ICCest) in R is `ICCest(column_a, column_b, data)`.
However, there is no way to pass an unquoted column name through rpy2.

If I execute the code below,

```
import numpy as np
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import DataFrame
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
df = DataFrame.from_object({
    'a': np.arange(20).repeat(5),
    'b': np.arange(100),
})
ICC = importr("ICC")
ICC.ICCest('a', 'b', df)
```

it will error out and give warnings as follow:

```
WARNING:rpy2.rinterface_lib.callbacks:R[write to console]: Error in eval(as.name(y), data, parent.frame()) : object 'b' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> -> eval -> eval

WARNING:rpy2.rinterface_lib.callbacks:R[write to console]: In addition: 
WARNING:rpy2.rinterface_lib.callbacks:R[write to console]: Warning message:

WARNING:rpy2.rinterface_lib.callbacks:R[write to console]: In (function (x, y, data = NULL, alpha = 0.05, CI.type = c("THD",  :
WARNING:rpy2.rinterface_lib.callbacks:R[write to console]: 

WARNING:rpy2.rinterface_lib.callbacks:R[write to console]:  passing a character string to 'y' is deprecated since ICC vesion 2.3.0 and will not be supported in future versions. The argument to 'y' should either be an unquoted column name of 'data' or an object
```

Note the last line of warning.
How do I even pass "an unquoted column name of 'data'" with rpy2?

Comment: What happens when you try `ICC.ICCest(a, b, df)` without the quotes around your `a` and `b`?

Comment: NameError: name 'a' is not defined. This is Python, after all.

Comment: The error looks like it's actually only about the `'y'` parameter and removing the quotes from that. So how about `ICC.ICCest('a', b, df)`?

Comment: No. I don't think that's how Python work.

Answer (score 0):

```
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import DataFrame, FloatVector
df = DataFrame({
    'a': FloatVector(np.arange(20).repeat(5)),
    'b': FloatVector(np.arange(100)),
})
```

Once I convert numpy arrays to `FloatVector`, the code works.

Also, it's better to use `as.name` or `as.symbol` here:

```
ICC.ICCest(base.as_name('a'), base.as_name('b'), df)
```